# How can I change already created Expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have kind of following class:

```
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I am passing `IEnumerable<Entity>>` as data source to kendo grid (I think it does not matter, but added here for clearability of question).

I want to implement server side filtering, and have implemented a separate `input[text]` field on the page, and adding filters on the client side in the following way:

```
var grid = $(e).data('kendoGrid');
var columns = grid.columns;
var columnTypes = grid.dataSource.options.schema.model.fields;
for (var i = 0; i < columns.length; i++) {
    if (columns[i].field) {
        var columnDataType = columnTypes[columns[i].field].type;
        if (columnDataType == 'number' && !isNaN(Number(value))) {
            var filter = { field: columns[i].field, operator: "eq", value: Number(value) };
        } else if (columnDataType == 'string') {
            var filter = { field: columns[i].field, operator: "contains", value: value };
        }

        gridListFilter.filters.push(filter);
    }
}

var gridDataSource = grid.dataSource;
console.log(gridListFilter);
gridDataSource.filter(gridListFilter);
```

On the server side I have implement the following algorithm for filtering in virtualization handler method:

```
IQueryable<Entity> query = this.GetQuery<Entity>();
foreach (var item in dataSourceRequest.Filters)
{
    var paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TReturnType), "item");
    var expr = item.CreateFilterExpression(paramExpr);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TReturnType, bool>>(expr, paramExpr);
    query = query.Where(lambda);
}
```

where `dataSourceRequest` is of type `DataSourceRequest` from telerik library. Matters that `item.CreateFilterExpression` produces a `BinaryExpression` of the following representation:

```
item => (IIF((item != null), item.Id, 0) == 6999142) OrElse 
((IIF((item != null), item.Name, null) ?? "").ToLower().Contains("6999142".ToLower()))
```

Where "6999142" is search string which I have get from `input[text]` from view. And I want to modify this expression in the following manner:

```
item => (IIF((item != null), item.Id, 0).ToString().Contains("6999142")) OrElse 
((IIF((item != null), item.Name, null) ?? "").ToLower().Contains("6999142".ToLower()))
```

Is there a way to change already created `Expression` without re-creating the new one?

If it is, can you provide the sample code for modifying, as I have no idea to what I should start from.

Comment: No, expression trees are immutable by design.

Comment: @JonSkeet ok, and what about traversing this expression tree and copying some nodes to the new expression tree and replacing some nodes by another? Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654266.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to @JonSkeet's comment I have implemented the following

```
internal class KendoExpressionModifier : ExpressionVisitor
{
    public Expression Modify(Expression expression)
    {
        return Visit(expression);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitConditional(ConditionalExpression node)
    {
        //converting result of conditional expression to string
        return Expression.Call(node.IfTrue, typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString"));
    }

    protected override Expression VisitBinary(BinaryExpression node)
    {
        //replacing '==' operator with '.Contains'
        if (node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Equal)
        {
            var left = this.Visit(node.Left);
            var right = this.Visit(node.Right);

            return Expression.Call(left, typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"), right);
        }
        //replacing expression 'a.ToString() ?? ""' with 'a != null ? a.ToString() : ""'
        else if (node.NodeType == ExpressionType.Coalesce)
        {
            var left = this.Visit(node.Left) as MethodCallExpression;

            return Expression.Condition(
                Expression.MakeBinary(
                    ExpressionType.NotEqual, 
                    left.Object, 
                    Expression.Constant(null)), 
                left, 
                Expression.Constant(string.Empty));
        }

        return base.VisitBinary(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
    {
        //replacing constant numeric value with its string representation
        if (node.Value.GetType() != typeof(string))
        {
            return Expression.Call(node, typeof(object).GetMethod("ToString"));
        }

        return base.VisitConstant(node);
    }
}
```

And the call to this modifier:

```
var kendoExpressionModifier = new KendoExpressionModifier();
expr = kendoExpressionModifier.Modify(expr);
```

produces the required result. So, I hope it will help someone.